# incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'. for a balancecode

Tags: sql-server, subquery

This is happening on line 4.

```
UPDATE CashBalances 
   SET Balance1=0,
       Balance2=0 
 WHERE PID=100040 
   AND Date='20081024' 

IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 
  INSERT INTO CashBalances(PID,Date,BalanceCode,Balance1,Balance2,CCY)
    VALUES (100040 ,'20081024', (SELECT TOP 1 balancecode 
                                   FROM cashbalances 
                                  WHERE date=(SELECT MAX(Date) 
                                                FROM CashBalances 
                                               WHERE PID=100040) 
  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 SELECT 'I' AS balancecode),0,0,' ')
```

I am trying to retrieve a balancecode where date is the max from a specific pid.
If zero rows are returned then return 'I' as a balancecode.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use `IF` inside subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Just create another valiable and then insert it:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(PID) FROM CashBalances WHERE PID=100040) > 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE CashBalances SET Balance1=0,Balance2=0 WHERE PID=100040 AND Date='20081024';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --Here your create it, could be that you use different type
    DECLARE @ConditionalValue NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'I';

    --Here you set it with a right value that you need on condition
    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 
    SET @ConditionalValue = (SELECT TOP 1  
                                FROM cashbalances 
                                WHERE date=(SELECT MAX(Date) 
                                        FROM CashBalances 
                                        WHERE PID=100040))
    --Insert your final value
    INSERT INTO CashBalances(PID, Date, BalanceCode, Balance1, Balance2, CCY)
    VALUES (100040 ,'20081024', @ConditionalValue,0,0,' ')
END
```

Comment: In this code there will always be an insert. I think there should only  be an update when there were no rows updated. There is '@@ROWCOUNT = 0' in the question.

Comment: @Peter could be, lets wait OP for more details

Comment: @Peter you're right it's always inserting a new record.

Comment: @Nkhumisenikholophe and you need insert always? Or not?

Comment: @ Teo van kot - If the record exist where PID=100040 on that date, Don't insert a new row just update the balance1 and 2. Else Insert

Answer (score 1):

Either stick to select or values. Not Both. As Arvo mentioned, you can not use if in a query. You can use case instead, but you don't need it here.

```
update CashBalances 
set Balance1=0, Balance2=0 
where PID=100040 AND Date='20081024' 

if @@ROWCOUNT=0 
Begin
    declare @Balancecode char(1)='I'

    select top 1 @Balancecode =  balancecode
    from cashbalances cb
    where PID=100040
    order by date desc

    insert into CashBalances(PID,Date,BalanceCode,Balance1,Balance2,CCY)
    values (100040 ,'20081024', @balanceCode,0,0,' ')
end
```

Comment: You should make an effort to be **consistent** with how you write the SQL keywords - *either* write them in all UPPERCASE (SELECT, FROM), or write them in all lowercase (select, from), or in mixed case (Select, From) - but please **pick one style** and then **stick to it** - don't mix all of them together!

Comment: @marc_s thank you for your feedback. I prefer lowercase, but copied some of the code. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a different way as follows.

If there is no data on `PID=100040 AND  Date='20081024'` Insert query will work.

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
    INSERT INTO CashBalances(PID,Date,BalanceCode,Balance1,Balance2,CCY)
    VALUES 
    (
        100040 ,
        ''20081024'',
        COALESCE ((SELECT TOP 1 balancecode FROM cashbalances WHERE date=(SELECT MAX(Date) FROM CashBalances WHERE PID=100040), ''I'',
        0,
        0,
        '' ''
    )';


SELECT @Query = 'UPDATE CashBalances 
                    SET Balance1=0,
                    Balance2=0 
                  WHERE PID=100040 
                 AND Date=''20081024''
                 '
WHERE 
    PID=100040 AND 
    Date='20081024' 


EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE CashBalances SET Balance1=0,Balance2=0 WHERE PID=258 AND 
Date='20081024' 

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0  
BEGIN 
DECLARE @BalCode Char(1) 
SET @BalCode = ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 Balancecode
FROM CashBalances 
WHERE Date=(SELECT MAX(Date) FROM CashBalances WHERE PID=258)),'I')

INSERT INTO CashBalances(PID,Date,BalanceCode,Balance1,Balance2,CCY)
VALUES (258 ,'20081024',@BalCode,0,0,' ')
END

--- @ teo van tok
```